# How to get first character from words in flutter dart?

Tags: dart

Let's say we have a name set to "Ben Bright". I want to output to the user "BB", with the first characters of each word. I tried with the `split()` method, but I failed to do it with dart.

```
String getInitials(bank_account_name) {
  List<String> names = bank_account_name.split(" ");
  String initials;
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    initials = '${names[i]}';
  }
  return initials;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Just a slight modification since you only need the first letters**

```
String getInitials(bank_account_name) {
  List<String> names = bank_account_name.split(" ");
  String initials = "";
  int numWords = 2;
  
  if(numWords < names.length) {
    numWords = names.length;
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
    initials += '${names[i][0]}';
  }
  return initials;
}
```

Edit:

- You can set the value of `num_words` to print the intials of those many words.
- If the `bank_account_name` is a 0 letter word, then return an empty string
- If the `bank_account_name` contains lesser words than `num_words`, print the initials of all the words in `bank_account_name`.

Comment: I got a range error. How do I ensure that it always returns two letters even if the words are more than 2?

Comment: Do you need the initials of only the first 2 words? You may now check the edit.

Comment: I just discovered that this only works for at least three words. I get this error (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0) while trying to use for two words

Comment: The older code produced when an error a 0 or 1 letter word was passed as the parameter. I have made new edits. Should work fine now! :)

Comment: I prefer this solution because it's more readable.

Answer (score 35):

Allow me to give a shorter solution than the other mentioned:

```
void main() {
  print(getInitials('')); //
  print(getInitials('Ben')); // B
  print(getInitials('Ben ')); // B
  print(getInitials('Ben Bright')); // BB
  print(getInitials('Ben Bright Big')); // BB
}

String getInitials(String bank_account_name) => bank_account_name.isNotEmpty
    ? bank_account_name.trim().split(' ').map((l) => l[0]).take(2).join()
    : '';
```

The `take(2)` part ensures we only take up to two letters.

**EDIT (7th October 2021):**

Or if we must be able to handle multiple spaces between the words we can do (thanks @StackUnderflow for notice):

```
void main() {
  print(getInitials('')); //
  print(getInitials('Ben')); // B
  print(getInitials('Ben ')); // B
  print(getInitials('Ben Bright')); // BB
  print(getInitials('Ben Bright Big')); // BB
  print(getInitials('Ben  Bright    Big')); // BB
}

String getInitials(String bankAccountName) => bankAccountName.isNotEmpty
    ? bankAccountName.trim().split(RegExp(' +')).map((s) => s[0]).take(2).join()
    : '';
```

Notice that `split` takes a `RegExp(' +')` compared to the original solution.

Comment: I have an issue bro. I have a listView whereby am sing this function for setting the leading widget part. This code works only for at least three words. When the loops hits lists that contain less words, I get this error. (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Comment: Ok, so you have names there are empty? Because it should work as you can see with only one word.

Comment: I have updated my solution so it is more stable against corner cases. If it still not works I will be happy if you could provide some test strings so I can create a method there works for you cases.

Comment: It throws a RangeError for a string with 2 spaces in the middle e.g `ABC  XYZ`. You can fix that with a regex:
`str.trim().replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ').split(' ').map((s) => s[0]).take(2).join();`

Comment: @StackUnderflow No need for the `replaceAll`. We can just `split` using `RegExp(' +')`.

Comment: It also throws a RangeError for strings with just spaces e.g `' '`. I fixed it by trimming the string before checking if it is empty: ```String getInitials(String bankAccountName) => bankAccountName.trim().isNotEmpty```.

Answer (score 10):

```
var string = 'William Henry Gates';

var output = getInitials(string: string, limitTo: 1); // W
var output = getInitials(string: string, limitTo: 2); // WH
var output = getInitials(string: string); // WHG
```

```dart
String getInitials({String string, int limitTo}) {
  var buffer = StringBuffer();
  var split = string.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0 ; i < (limitTo ?? split.length); i ++) {
    buffer.write(split[i][0]);
  }

  return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: @na2axl I didn't know he needs for more than 2 words, please check out the updated solution.

Comment: I got a range (index) error. Am using this function for a listView.

Comment: How do I ensure that it always returns two letters even if the words are more than 2?

Comment: I just discovered that this only works for at least three words. I get this error (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0) while trying to use for two words

Comment: @bensofter It was an easy fix, you had to use `split.length` instead of `2`, I have updated the code, please see it.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution can be found below. It takes care of empty strings, single word strings and situations where anticipated word count is less than actual word count:

```
static String getInitials(String string, {int limitTo}) {
  var buffer = StringBuffer();
  var wordList = string.trim().split(' ');
  
  if (string.isEmpty)
    return string;

  // Take first character if string is a single word
  if (wordList.length <= 1)
    return string.characters.first;

  /// Fallback to actual word count if
  /// expected word count is greater
  if (limitTo != null && limitTo > wordList.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
      buffer.write(wordList[i][0]);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
  }

  // Handle all other cases
  for (var i = 0; i < (limitTo ?? wordList.length); i++) {
    buffer.write(wordList[i][0]);
  }
  return buffer.toString();
}
```

**Edit:**
I actually use this for `CircleAvatar`s with no images in my projects.

Comment: error: The getter 'characters' isn't defined for the type 'String'.

Answer (score 1):

I used CopsOnRoad solution but I was getting the following error.

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

So I modified it to

```dart
String getInitials(String string, [int limitTo = 2]) {
  if (string == null || string.isEmpty) {
    return '';
  }

  var buffer = StringBuffer();
  var split = string.split(' ');

  //For one word
  if (split.length == 1) {
    return string.substring(0, 1);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < (limitTo ?? split.length); i++) {
    buffer.write(split[i][0]);
  }

  return buffer.toString();
}
```

Here are some tests in case you are interested

```dart
void main() {
  group('getInitials', () {
    test('should process one later word name correctly', () {
      final result = getInitials('J');

      expect(result, 'J');
    });

    test('should process one word name correctly', () {
      final result = getInitials('John');

      expect(result, 'J');
    });

    test('should process two word name correctly', () {
      final result = getInitials('John Mamba');

      expect(result, 'JM');
    });

    test('should process more than two word name correctly', () {
      final result = getInitials('John Mamba Kanzu');

      expect(result, 'JM');
    });

    test('should return empty string when name is null', () {
      final result = getInitials(null);

      expect(result, '');
    });

    test('should return empty string when name is empty', () {
      final result = getInitials('');

      expect(result, '');
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String getInitials(full_name) {
  List<String> names = full_name.split(" ");
  print("org::: $full_name");
  print("list ::: $names");
  print("Substring  ::: ${names[0].substring(0,1)}");
  String initials = "";
  int numWords = 2;

  numWords = names.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
  {
    initials += '${names[i].substring(0,1)}';
    print("the initials are $initials");
  }
  return initials;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On Nov, 2022
Working solution using Regex:

```
 String getInitials(String string) => string.isNotEmpty
 ? string.trim().split(RegExp(' +')).map((s) => s[0]).join() 
 : '' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: This will allow you to get the first character of any number of words in a sentence.

```
   static String getInitials(String bankName) {
      final names = bankName.split(" ");
      String initials = "";
      int numWords = 2;

      if (numWords < names.length) {
        numWords = names.length;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
        initials += names[i].isNotEmpty ? '${names[i][0]}' : '';
      }
      return initials;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
getFirstCharFromWord({required String word}){
   String firstChar="";
   word.split(" ").forEach((element) {
       String fc= element.trim().toString();
       fc.isNotEmpty?firstChar+=fc.substring(0,1):"";
   });
   return firstChar;
}
```